# Images of different sizes in uploads folder wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When add an image in media, creates multiple images of different sizes.

When upload image.png, create image-150x112.png

I want have only image upload. How do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress automatically resizes the images to use as thumbnails or posts so to cut down the amount of bandwidth being used up.

If you really really want to, you can unset them but i would advise against it if your using very large images which will use up a lot bandwidth.

### Option 1

Go into `settings` -> `media` and change all of the numbers to `0`. This means the resize wont happen.

### Option 2

Add this code to your functions.php file in the theme

```
function unset_image_resizing() {
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}

add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'unset_image_resizing');
```